# WordPress only saves the post as a new revision

Tags: wordpress

​Hi.

I've been using a theme for a couple of years now with no problem. But recently, I cannot update any post.
https://themeforest.net/item/photography-responsive-photography-theme/13304399

The problem is that on the admin when I change a page and click on update, it says "page updated" but when I refresh the post edit page (on the admin) again, it shows the previous content. However, it shows all the changes as a revision that is not saved as the current one. Right now, I have over 200 revisions.
It is worth mentioning, that when I change the theme, updating works fine when I change and click on update. But, when I change back the theme, it shows again the old content.

Comment: Are you using latest version of the theme? There may be an issue with functional part due to WordPress update

Comment: Try to create new test wp instance and install the theme and perform a test. That will be the better option to trace the issue

Comment: I am using the latest update of the theme, WordPress, and all the plugins. I reinstalled both the WordPress and the theme and it didn't work. Besides, I am using this theme on 2 different websites on different servers, and they both have the same problem.
I am pretty sure there must be a problem with the theme as switching to the default theme solves it, but I can't find the issue.
I bought the theme from ThemeForest a few years ago, and the support has already been expired and I have to pay 40$ to be able to renew the support and submit a ticket to a problem that is obviously their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The theme was super old and the client hasn't updated the theme for quite a long time. I updated the theme and the problem has solved.
By the way, the reason I haven't tried this in the first place was that the client told me they already have updated the theme which was incorrect.